# Eigenvalues- Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am given that the eigenvectors of a 3x3 matrix A are v1 = [3, 1, 1], v2 = [-3, 1, -3], and v3 = [3, 0, 2]. I also know that the corresponding eigenvalues are 2, 3, -3, respectively. I know this matrix, A, is diagonalizable. I cannot seem to figure out what the values of the invertible matrix S and diagonal matrix B that diagonalize A are. Any help in finding the S matrix would be greatly appreciated. I know I can figure out the B matrix once I get the S matrix, by way of B = SAS^(-1).

Thank you in advance for your help!!

Comment: It's just the matrix consisting of your eigenvectors (in the right order). Remember, you are just changing bases here.

Comment: In this situation (a basis of eigenvectors) it is always the case that the diagonalizing matrix S is built by inserting the eigenvectors as its columns, and the resulting diagonal matrix consists of the corresponding eigenvalues.

Comment: So, are you saying that A=S? I tried that and it was incorrect, what order do they go in?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have a diagonalizable $3\times3$ matrix $A$, and suppose we have calculated the eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ and the corresponding eigenvectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$. When you diagonalize the matrix you are in fact doing a basis transformation: the eigenvectors are three linearly independent vectors and thus span the space, so they do form a basis. Maybe you have, maybe you haven't learned how to write a matrix in a different basis, but here's how it's done. Let $P$ be the matrix with the eigenvectors as its columns, and let $D$ be the matrix with the eigenvalues on the diagonal. After a basic course in linear algebra or some reading on the internet, you can convince yourself that
\begin{align}
A=PDP^{-1},
\end{align}
where as we said we have 
\begin{align}
P=\begin{pmatrix}
| & | & | \\
v_1 & v_2 & v_3 \\
| & | & |
\end{pmatrix},\quad D=\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \lambda_2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \lambda_3
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
Thus we see that we can, given $D$ and the eigenvectors, calculate the original matrix $A$. Note the order of the eigenvectors and the eigenvalues. It doesn't matter how your order them as long as you do it consistenly, so if you have $v_2$ as your first column and $v_1$ as your second, you should also interchange $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$. I hope this makes things a little more clear.

Comment: So, are you saying that P is equal to the three eigenvectors that I was given? Or, do I have modify/make them an eigenbasis and then those are the vectors that make up the P matrix?

Comment: Yes. No, no modification, they ARE a basis, and P has them as columns, just like I said in my answer.